# Download post as text file on wordpress blog post page

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there anyway to download individual blog posts as text (or html) files ? I am trying to generate the markup for a html email based on the content of the blog post.

The content of the files would be the excerpt.

What would be the easiest way to generate these files? I am not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Nice idea, go for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Wordpress to generate email newsletter templates on like a dozen of the sites I've built.

Just create a new page template (see [the associated Page Templates Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)) designed with your markup for the HTML newsletter (usually very simple since most email clients have unbelievably shitty HTML/CSS support that's a solid decade behind the rest of the internet).

Then use template functions and a custom loop to get the blog post or other content from Wordpress you want, display it in the template, and then when you view the page you can just copy the HTML!  Note that you probably want to write your own header and footer for this template to keep it slim (rather than using `get_header()` and `get_footer()`.

Answer (score 0):

Take the post body and do a `strip_tags()`.